# Strategy for finding a missing mouse event in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Will make this brief, I have a game map with units on it and had finalized a fully interactive minimap where the units on the minimap have event listeners for rollover/rollout (displays a small popup unit data summary) and click (selects the "real" unit on the main game map and scrolls the viewpoint to that location). All done, tested, working.

I then implement an interactive scrollable unit list with more status summary data and dozens of objects with rollover/rollout/click listeners. All tested and working fine.

Then I go back and look at my minimap, and the listeners on the mini-ships aren't working anymore. Things tried:

1. Debug code to make sure listeners still being added
2. Debug to watch the one place where I remove those listeners to make sure that ain't happening unexpectedly
3. Debug to watch all the places I refresh that dialog to make sure every iteration adds the listeners back
4. Can't see that there is any transparent object on top intercepting
5. Checked mini-ship parents to make sure I didn't turn off mouseChildren or something like that somewhere
6. No added stage-level listener, in fact I killed all of them temporarily to test this

What happens when I debug with a breakpoint on the mini-ship listener handler is nada. It's no longer receiving mouse events. So either something I haven't thought of has stopped them from listening or something I don't know of is intercepting.

So what is the strategy here? How can I find the break in the chain?

Comment: And it's found and I failed at 3) above - I found a place getting commonly called where I refreshed that dialog without remembering to subsequently call the function that adds the listeners to some of the content. Which is why you probably shouldn't do it that way. That said, any advice on things I could have tried that I didn't try?

Comment: mouseEnabled would ignore the listeners on that object as well (mouseChildren only disables events for the children of that object, not the object itself) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well knowing what the actual problem was certainly gives us the advantage of hindsight... that being said, you could have detected the error by adding a trace call inside your function that adds the listener and another one inside your function that removes it. Then you would have seen that it isn't getting re-added. Or you could set break points there.

Comment: Thanks, that's the advice I was looking for to help next time around.